# unable to refactor code rails 4 query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Scenario is, I want to get all timeslots for 2 cases.

1. if doorman is true the query will be same
2. if doorman is false then need to add a parameter in the query

So, its the same query almost that will work for both cases with little modification.

Here is the query and code:

```
def self.latest_pickup_date current_zone,doorman
    if doorman
      latest_timeslot = Timeslot.where(dropoff_slots: '-1', zone_id: current_zone).order(:slot_date).last
    else
      latest_timeslot = Timeslot.where(dropoff_slots: '-1', zone_id: current_zone, doorman_type: "none").order(:slot_date).last
    end
    latest_timeslot.nil? ? Date.current : latest_timeslot.slot_date
  end
```

I would like to refactor my code and the query in a way to use the approach of DRY.

I do not want to write these queries twice in both cases. I need a better solution using code practices. Or if I am doing this right way, you can advice as well.

Plus need good professional code practices and code refactoring as well if anyone can help with.

Comment: Your question title is _unable to refactor_, why is you unable to refactor? Do you know about http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Зелёный I do not have that much good knowledge and my expertise are limited so I posted to get expert answer. My intention is not to get answer only. I can do myself as well.
well I don't know about codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should post this question to the http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do a `where` on an existing query, to add the additional condition, and use `try` in case the query is empty

```
def self.latest_pickup_date current_zone,doormam
  latest_timeslot = Timeslot.where(dropoff_slots: '-1', zone_id: current_zone).order(:slot_date)
  latest_timeslot = latest_timeslot.where(doorman_type: 'none') unless doorman
  latest_timeslot.last.try(:slot_date) || Date.current
end
```

Comment: Go for this approach. This is the cleanest solution

Comment: That's code make a two query, while it able make only one, also `try` it's a bad practice.

Comment: I am also thinking the same well. It look like it makes 2 queries. anyways it really works well. 
Why `try` is bad practice?

Comment: [_#try is a code smell_](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/)

Comment: It doesn't make two queries.  The query is only made when the results are requested.  That's how ActiveRecord relations work and it makes it easy to build queries incrementally without impact on your database.   As for `try` being a  "code smell", the alternative is some really clunky `latest_timeslot.last ? lastest_timeslot.last.slot_date : Date.current` ... for me the `try` is more elegant and readable.

Comment: I have used the `last` in my query not like that you wrote above. :) its more like `latest_timeslot.nil? ? Date.current : latest_timeslot.slot_date`. It could be clunky so accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the following refactored code, let me know if you like this approach.

```
def self.latest_pickup_date current_zone,doorman
  filters = {dropoff_slots: '-1', zone_id: current_zone}
  filters[:doorman_type] = "none" unless doorman

  latest_timeslot = Timeslot.where(filters).order(:slot_date).last

  latest_timeslot.nil? ? Date.current : latest_timeslot.slot_date
end
```

Comment: Could you please add comments in code as well? Thanks btw. Looks good.

Comment: Basically the where clause accepts a dictionary. So, you can either pass the filter columns and values separately or you can pass a dictionary. In the dictionary the key should be the column name and value should be the value you want to use to filter. That is what I have done here,

filters = {dropoff_slots: '-1', zone_id: current_zone} # The first two fields
filters[:doorman_type] = "none" unless doorman #The optional field

latest_timeslot = Timeslot.where(filters).order(:slot_date).last # The filter

When doorman is not null then, you add doorman_type to the dictionary.

Comment: Ok got that - could you add links to read more about filters?
plus one thing: `filters[:doorman_type]` this code is adding another key in filters? Am i right? I mean with other 2 keywords we are adding `filters[:doorman_type]` in our dictionary?

Comment: You can omit the `nil?` and the `Timeslot` constant. That's not clear and good solution.

Comment: Could you please attempt to make it more better one? Its even not cleat to me as well. @Зелёный